# grails app fails to start in Tomcat7 - can't get any useful information from log?

Tags: tomcat, grails, logging

I deployed a grails 2 app into a tomcat7 and it just won't start. I tried a bunch of things to get any information from the catalina.out or my apps log but all I get is

```
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8081"]
Jul 30, 2012 5:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8372 ms
```

I already put a logging.properties into /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes containing

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

but this doesn't give me any more information either.

Also, I changed the grails app's loglevel to debug but there is no error coming up either. Currently I have no clue how to get any useful information out of the tomcat or the app, helping me to find the error :(

Cheers,

Moritz

*Update:*

My Config.groovy looks like this for the environment I'm trying to run:

```
staging {
    def logDirectory = "/var/log/myApp"

    log4j = {
        appenders {
            rollingFile name: 'stacktrace', file: "${logDirectory}/stacktrace.log".toString(), maxFileSize: '10MB'
            rollingFile name: 'myLog', file: "${logDirectory}/myApp_debug.log".toString(), maxFileSize: '10MB'
        }

        root {
            // change the root logger to myLog file
            debug 'myLog'
        }

        debug  'grails.app'
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons' // Core artifact information such as class loading etc.
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web' //Grails web request processing
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping' // URL mapping debugging
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins' //  Log plugin activity
        warn  'grails.spring' // See what Spring beans Grails and plugins are defining
        debug  'org.springframework' // See what Spring is doing
        debug  'org.hibernate' // See what Hibernate is doing
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet'  //  controllers
        debug  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages' //  GSP
        info  'org.apache.catalina' // tomcat

        // set level for my messages; this uses the root logger (and thus the tomcatLog file)
        debug 'myApp_debug.log'
    }

    grails.serverURL = "someUrl"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in all the log files - catalina.out rarely has the real issue in it. logs/localhost.2012-07-30.log and stacktrace.log are your best bets.

Answer (score -2):

Alright so I finally found the bug. I couldn't find any way to get a warning or error inside the log though. Anyway, my bug lied in the searchable configuration of my app.